# Get Height of IonHeader from within Component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

**Ionic-Angular 5**

Using https://github.com/roman-rr/cupertino-pane, I am trying to offset the top by the height of the `ion-header` i.e. `height = 100% - (height of header)`.

I'm within a child component so I can't `ViewChild` the header, though I'm not sure that works for `ion-` elements... Is there a way I can programmatically calculate the height of the `ion-header` element as it'll obviously vary depending on device?

Thanks,

Comment: So I can add an ID to my `ion-header` such as `map-header` then getElementById().offsetHeight. Is this bad practice?

Comment: u can use something like document.querySelector('home-page ion-header').clientHeight or give the ion-header an id and use document.getElementById('the-id').clientHeight

Answer (score 0):

In your component :

```
@ViewChild('header') header: ElementRef


getHeaderHeight(){
  return this.header.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
}
```

Source : [Ionic team](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-ion-header-height-in-angular-the-right-way/186481/2)